# What kind of liquid do I need for rosemary smelling incense and rosemary flavoured vape liquid?

Tags: untagged

In my garden I have planted some rosemary and I want to make:

1. rosemary-smelling incense and
2. rosemary-flavoured vape liquid (combined with other flavours as well).

But I do not know

1. what process to use in order to make these liquids.
2. what kind of liquids to make for each case.

Via asking around on Reddit and Twitch chat streams I found that I can make either:

1. Essential oils using a carrier oil such as almond oil.
2. Some sort of alcohol/water based liquid.

But what kind of liquid do I need to make for each case?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you **should not** try to make vape liquid at all. This stuff gets inhaled and partially absorbed by your lungs, so you should treat it with the same consideration as a medication. I've heard of a case where someone put some regular garden herbs (unfortunately I forgot *which* herbs, but they were considered harmless cooking ingredients) into a cigarette and it landed them in hospital for 2 days. Don't put any chemicals into your body unless you understand what they do or some professional who knows about this stuff tells you that it's safe.

As a rule of thumb water extracts the taste of an ingredient and oil extracts the smell of it. So if you want to extract the scent of rosemary for an aroma lamp, the usual process is to infuse a neutral carrier oil with the ingredient you want.

Cut the ingredient very fine and put them into an airtight container like a glass bottle. Slightly heat the carrier oil (but only *slightly*!) and pour it into the bottle with the prepared ingredients. Close the bottle and wait for 2 weeks.

The same process but with alcohol is used when the ingredient doesn't have a lot of oil (like vanilla or cedar wood).

Once the extraction is done, you can use the oil to scent your home by many different ways like:

- putting a few drops into a scent lamp or fragrance block
- sticking one or several wooden sticks into the oil to help it evaporate
- mixing a small amount of isopropyl alcohol into it and letting it evaporate directly from the bottle

Comment: What oil can I use. Would sunflower oil do the job? (Because can be found in bulk for cheap)

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas You can use anything that doesn't have a strong smell. I don't have any experience with making scented oils but I think sunflower oil should work. Keep in mind that all natural oils get rancid after a time (usually about a year), so by producing scented oil in bulk you may have to discard a lot of it if you cannot use it up in time.

Comment: Hate to break it to you re vape flavors but those are universally artificial chemically derived compounds... not herbal extracts. [Comprehensive overview of common e-liquid ingredients](https://tobaccocontrol.bmj.com/content/30/2/185)